# How do I get parameter from child route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4dF9HI8mMZoWjjAawFVt?p=preview) What I would expect is to hit the second link and see `Angular 1234` thanks to the parameter I have in my child config...

```
const TWO_ROUTES = [
    {
        path: "test/:id",
        component: ChildComponent
    }
];
```

What I actually see is `Angular undefined`. What am I missing? How do I access the param in the child route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `this.route.params['id']`, it should be:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.name = `Angular ${this.route.params.value['id']}`;
}
```

You can also use:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.name = `Angular ${this.route.snapshot.params['id']}`;
}
```

Check [official Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) for more info about Routing & Navigation.

Comment: Ahhh I see so does that mean that without the snapshot it returns an observable?

Comment: Weird according to the docs...

"ActivatedRoute: the one-stop-shop for route information" And "params: An Observable that contains the required and optional parameters specific to the route."

but `this.route.params.then((params) => {
      this.name = `Angular ${params['id']}`
    })` doesn't work

Comment: Yes, exactly. Without the snapshot you get an observable. Observable are unwrapped with `.subscribe()`, not `.then()` (you're confusing with promises).